# how is the state parameter determined?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, pressure, radiation

For radiation, dark energy and dust the pressure and energy density are related, respectively, by:

$p=\frac{1}{3}\rho$

$p=-\rho$

$p=0$

My question is why? How does one show that this is how pressure and energy density are related for these substances? Is it derived from the stress-energy tensor?

Comment: could you provide the source where you got those relations?

Comment: It's in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_%28cosmology%29) Wikipedia article under non-relativistic matter, ultra-relativistic matter and acceleration of cosmic inflation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p=\frac{1}{3}\rho$ is the well-known equation of state of a [photon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas#Thermodynamics_of_a_black_body_photon_gas). It may be derived by looking at the ultra-relativistic limit of the energy momentum tensor for a bunch of particles.$^1$

$p=-\rho$ follows from the fact that the energy momentum tensor of $\Lambda$-style dark energy is proportional to the metric. Thus, at a point and in the proper coordinates, $T_{\mu\nu}\propto \eta_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$. Since $T_{00}=\rho$ and $T_{ii}=p$ (no sum), we find $p=-\rho$.

$p=0$ follows from the *definition* of "dust." Dust is defined by this equation of state.

---

$^1$ A decent explanation is given in S. Weinberg, *Gravitation and Cosmology* (1972) on pages 50-51.